# Random KDE Plasma crash reports

Tags: kubuntu, kde, crash

I keep getting reports that certain apps crashed or 'closed unexpectedly', whilst usually they either didn't really crash (by my knowledge) or weren't opened in the first place.

I get a dialog screen telling me that '*app*' closed unexpectedly, offering me details and asking if I want to send details to developers.

When I choose 'details', usually it just tells me which executable supposedly crashed and its path.

Apps which I've had this happen to:

- Kwin
- Kate
- Audacity
- Dolphin

Usually when this happens, a couple of reports come in from different supposed crashes.

I'm running Kubuntu 16.10 with all latest updates installed.